# Configuring Kate text editor to compile a latex file

Tags: editors, ubuntu, kile

I am trying to use the KDE Kate text editor for latex.  Essentially, what I want is to be able to click "build" and have it run 
pdflatex

I read the [documentation for the build plugin](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/kate/kate-application-plugin-build.html), but I couldn't figure how to do it.  As a workaround, I can keep a terminal open and manually type pdflatex .tex whenever I want to compile.  I can also use BASH's keybinding to create a shortcut for that, but I would have to change it for each latex file I want to edit.

I'm also aware of [Kile](https://kile.sourceforge.io/), which is based on Kate.  However, that is more like a full IDE, which is not what I want.

If it matters, I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: This might probably of help if you cannot figure out how to make `KDE Kate` work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors.

Comment: In your question you say that you couldn't figure out how to use the build plugin, could you please clarify what the problem was? What did you try, which steps of using the plugin didn't you understand? There is an example on https://kate-editor.org/2011/08/09/maintainer-needed-kate-external-tools-plugin/#comment-974 which might be useful, it suggests that you can use `%f` as a reference to the current file, which means you could try to use `pdflatex %f` as a build target, either with or without the terminal call around it.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include the answer. Instead, ask @Marijn to post an answer you can accept.

Answer (score 1):

To get the Kate build plugin to compile a LaTeX file, set the "working directory/command" in the Target Settings tab to `pdflatex %f`.

Source: https://kate-editor.org/2011/08/09/maintainer-needed-kate-external-tools-plugin/#comment-974.

Comment: The external tools plugin is back, and heavily improved: https://kate-editor.org/post/2019/2019-09-21-external-tools-plugin/